# UnboundLocalError and i don't know why

Tags: python

Hello i'm a beginner in python and when i launch this code i have

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'selected' referenced before assignment`

so i search and i found some info about global variable so i try to update my code like this:

```
def scrollUP(event,):
    #print("scrollUP")
    global tabAlaphabet
    global selected
    if selected == len(tabAlaphabet) - 1:
        selected = 0
    else:   
        selected += 1
    print(tabAlaphabet[selected])
```

and i have :

```
NameError: global name 'tabAlaphabet' is not defined
```

so i don't know how debbug this :/

thank's for your help :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tabAlphabet` (without the third `a`)?

Comment: i'm so bad -_- it was this thanks ^^'

Answer (score 0):

You simply had a spelling error.  `tabAlaphabet` should be `tabAlphabet`.

A trick that I like to use to help catch those annoying grammatical mistakes is to read your code backwards.  This way, you dont attach any meaning to your code and you can catch those silly mistakes with ease.